# Is there a way to merge rows in a df by concatenating certain columns based on another df, and summing the rest of the columns?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a "master" dataframe that has the product codes and names of a lot of materials along with their monthly consumption. something like:

| product code | Name | Consumption A | Consumption B | Consumption C | Consumption D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | AA | 100 | 120 | 130 | 140 |
| 456 | BB | 5 | 7 | 9 | 11 |
| 789 | CC | 12 | 5 | 33 | 89 |
| 134 | AD | 4 | 17 | 37 | 57 |
| 467 | BD | 1 | 3 | 5 | 7 |

And I also have a second table that has a list of some product codes that are "alternatives" or substitutes, like:

| Product Code | Alt Code |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 134 |
| 456 | 467 |

How can I can use this second dataframe to process the first one such that it becomes:

| product code | Name | Consumption A | Consumption B | Consumption C | Consumption D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 / 134 | AA / AD | 104 | 137 | 167 | 197 |
| 456 / 467 | BB / BD | 6 | 10 | 14 | 18 |
| 789 | CC | 12 | 5 | 33 | 89 |

where the product codes and names have been concatenated into the same cell, the quantities summed, and the "duplicates" of the alternatives deleted?

There may be places where a single "main" code has multiple alternatives, but they will always be listed with the main code in the first column, and the alternative in the "alt code" column. I would ideally like to merge all alternative rows into a single one using the same bit of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom group and `groupby.agg`:

```
group = master['product code'].map(lambda x: alternatives.set_index('Product Code')['Alt Code'].get(x, x))

d = {c: 'sum' for c in master.columns}

out = (master
 .astype({'product code': str})
 .groupby(group, as_index=False)
 .agg({**d, **{'product code': ' / '.join, 'Name': ' / '.join}})
)
```

output:

```
  product code     Name  Consumption A  Consumption B  Consumption C  Consumption D
0    123 / 134  AA / AD            104            137            167            197
1    456 / 467  BB / BD              6             10             14             18
2          789       CC             12              5             33             89
```