# How can I use custom groups and groupby.agg to merge rows in a df by concatenating certain columns and summing the rest based on another df?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

This is a bit of a follow-up to [an earlier question I had asked a little over a year ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72715775/14349590)

I have a "master" dataframe that has the product codes and names of a lot of materials along with their monthly consumption. something like:

| product code | Name | Consumption A | Consumption B | Consumption C | Consumption D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | AA | 100 | 120 | 130 | 140 |
| 456 | BB | 5 | 7 | 9 | 11 |
| 789 | CC | 12 | 5 | 33 | 89 |
| 134 | AD | 4 | 17 | 37 | 57 |
| 467 | BD | 1 | 3 | 5 | 7 |
| 179 | ED | 6 | 19 | 30 | 61 |
| 426 | FD | 8 | 5 | 2 | 13 |

And I also have a second table that has a list of some product codes that are "alternatives" or substitutes, like:

| Product Code | Alt Code |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 134 |
| 123 | 179 |
| 123 | 426 |
| 456 | 467 |

(The difference from the previous one is that now, the same "Product Code" can have multiple different "Alt Code"s)

How can I can use this second dataframe to process the first one such that it becomes:

| product code | Name | Consumption A | Consumption B | Consumption C | Consumption D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 / 134 / 179 / 426 | AA / AD / ED / FD | 118 | 161 | 199 | 271 |
| 456 / 467 | BB / BD | 6 | 10 | 14 | 18 |
| 789 | CC | 12 | 5 | 33 | 89 |

where the product codes and names have been concatenated into the same cell, the quantities summed, and the "duplicates" of the alternatives deleted?

Unlike last time, there are now places where a single "main" code has multiple alternatives, but they will always be listed with the main code in the first column, and the alternative in the "alt code" column. I would ideally like to merge all alternative rows into a single one using the same bit of code.

This is the code I have been trying to use, based on the answer I got last time:

```py
    if alt_name != "":
        altf = pd.read_excel(io=alt_name)
        group = df['Material'].map(lambda x: altf.set_index('Material')['Alt Material'].get(x, x))
        d = {c: 'sum' for c in df.columns}
        out = (df
               .astype({'Material': str})
               .groupby([group], as_index=False)
               .agg({**d, **{'Material': ' / '.join, 'Description': ' / '.join}})
               )
        df = out
```

alt_name is the name of the excel sheet with the columns, saved as "Material" and "Alt Material".

when I try running it with a table with multiple alternatives, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/[Location]/function_code_v2.py", line 285, in <module>
    trendcharts(file_name, zone, combinezones, month, numMonths, percent_wanted, trendgen, alt_name, save_directory)
  File "/Users/[Location]/function_code_v2.py", line 106, in trendcharts
    .agg({**d, **{'Material': ' / '.join, 'Description': ' / '.join}})
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/[Location]/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 1445, in aggregate
    result = op.agg()
             ^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/[Location]/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 175, in agg
    return self.agg_dict_like()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/[Location]/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 406, in agg_dict_like
    return self.agg_or_apply_dict_like(op_name="agg")
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/[Location]/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 1388, in agg_or_apply_dict_like
    result_index, result_data = self.compute_dict_like(
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/[Location]/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 480, in compute_dict_like
    getattr(obj._gotitem(key, ndim=1), op_name)(how, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/[Location]/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 275, in aggregate
    if self.ngroups == 0:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/[Location]/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 825, in ngroups
    return self.grouper.ngroups
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "properties.pyx", line 36, in pandas._libs.properties.CachedProperty.__get__
  File "/Users/[Location]/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/ops.py", line 758, in ngroups
    return len(self.result_index)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "properties.pyx", line 36, in pandas._libs.properties.CachedProperty.__get__
  File "/Users/[Location]/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/ops.py", line 769, in result_index
    return self.groupings[0].result_index.rename(self.names[0])
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "properties.pyx", line 36, in pandas._libs.properties.CachedProperty.__get__
  File "/Users/[Location]/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/grouper.py", line 718, in result_index
    return self.group_index
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "properties.pyx", line 36, in pandas._libs.properties.CachedProperty.__get__
  File "/Users/[Location]/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/grouper.py", line 722, in group_index
    codes, uniques = self._codes_and_uniques
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "properties.pyx", line 36, in pandas._libs.properties.CachedProperty.__get__
  File "/Users/[Location]/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/grouper.py", line 801, in _codes_and_uniques
    codes, uniques = algorithms.factorize(  # type: ignore[assignment]
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/[Location]/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py", line 795, in factorize
    codes, uniques = factorize_array(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/[Location]/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py", line 595, in factorize_array
    uniques, codes = table.factorize(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 7280, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.factorize
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 7194, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable._unique
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'
```

Comment: Can you please provide your two inputs as DataFrame constructors?

Comment: @mozway both dataframes (altf and df) were made using pd.read_excel(io=[file name]) with different files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same logic, aggregate using the common id:

```
d = {c: 'sum' for c in df.columns[1:]}
d['Name'] = lambda x: '/'.join(map(str, x))

out = (df
   .groupby(df['product code'].replace(altdf.set_index('Alt Code')['Product Code']))
   .agg(d).reset_index()
)
```

Then fix the product codes:

```
mapper = altdf.groupby('Product Code')['Alt Code'].agg(set)
out['product code'] = out['product code'].map(lambda x: '/'.join(map(str, sorted(mapper.get(x, set())|{x}))))
```

Output:

```
     product code         Name  Consumption A  Consumption B  Consumption C  Consumption D
0  123/134/179/426  AA/AD/ED/FD            118            161            199            271
1          456/467        BB/BD              6             10             14             18
2              789           CC             12              5             33             89
```

Comment: This is doing what you have indicated, but how can I also get `out` to show "AA" in row 0, "BB" in row 1, and 789 and "CC" in row 2?

Comment: @amanmore see update, I changed a bit the code to do that.

Comment: yup, looks like that did it! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.DataFrame({
    "pc": ["123", "456", "789", "134", "467", "179", "426"],
    "Name": ["AA", "BB", "CC", "AD", "BD", "ED", "FD"],
    "Consumption A": [100, 5, 12, 4, 1, 6, 8],
    "Consumption B": [120, 7, 5, 17, 3, 19, 5],
    "Consumption C": [130, 9, 33, 37, 5, 30, 2],
    "Consumption D": [140, 11, 89, 57, 7, 61, 13],
})

alt_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "PC": ["123", "123", "123", "456"],
    "Alt Code": ["134", "179", "426", "467"],
})
"""print(df)
   pc Name  Consumption A  Consumption B  Consumption C  Consumption D
0  123   AA            100            120            130            140
1  456   BB              5              7              9             11
2  789   CC             12              5             33             89
3  134   AD              4             17             37             57
4  467   BD              1              3              5              7
5  179   ED              6             19             30             61
6  426   FD              8              5              2             13

print(alt_df)
    PC Alt Code
0  123      134
1  123      179
2  123      426
3  456      467
"""
mapping = df['pc'].replace(alt_df.set_index('Alt Code')['PC'])
"""
print(mapping)
0    123
1    456
2    789
3    123
4    456
5    123
6    123
"""
#Important line.
gr = mapping.map(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x))) 
"""print(gr)
0    (1, 2, 3)
1    (4, 5, 6)
2    (7, 8, 9)
3    (1, 2, 3)
4    (4, 5, 6)
5    (1, 2, 3)
6    (1, 2, 3)
Name: pc, dtype: object"""

consumption_cols = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('Consumption')]  
"""
print(consumption_cols )
['Consumption A', 'Consumption B', 'Consumption C', 'Consumption D']
"""
agg_dict = {col: (col, 'sum') for col in consumption_cols}  
"""print(agg_dict)
{'Consumption A': ('Consumption A', 'sum'), 
'Consumption B': ('Consumption B', 'sum'),
 'Consumption C': ('Consumption C', 'sum'), 
'Consumption D': ('Consumption D', 'sum')}
"""
res1 = (df.groupby(gr)
         .agg(
             product_code=('pc', lambda x: '/'.join(sorted(set(x)))),
             Name=('Name', lambda x: '/'.join(x)),
             **agg_dict  # Unpack agg_dict dictionary
         )
         .reset_index().drop('pc', axis=1))  # Drop the 'pc' column

"""
print(res1.to_string())

     product_code         Name  Consumption A  Consumption B  Consumption C  Consumption D
0  123/134/179/426  AA/AD/ED/FD            118            161            199            271
1          456/467        BB/BD              6             10             14             18
2              789           CC             12              5             33             89
"""
```